# Keep showing old processes in nethogs

Tags: linux, networking, monitoring, bandwidth, network-monitoring

Nethogs stops showing idle processes after a while.  How can I make it keep showing them?
I want to have a complete history of processes for long time.  Is there any alternative to nethogs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any other program that shows network traffic by process, as nethogs does.  I guess your best option would be to edit the nethogs source.  Find and increase the constant that determines how long it shows idle processes, then rebuild nethogs.